# (Google Sheets) Replace values based on dropdown list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a sheet where a value gets replaced by whatever has been chosen in a dropdown list.

To illustrate:
Cell A has any value.

Cell B has a dropdown list with 3 options:

- Option 1 - Add 5 to whatever value Cell A has.
- Option 2 - Add 10 to whatever value Cell A has.
- Option 3 - Add 15 to whatever value Cell A has.

And then the value of Cell A gets updated with the new result.

Is this possible? If so, how?

**What I've tried:**

- Used the IF function, to no avail.
- Enabled Iterative Calculation, but the point of it is being able to edit Cell A into any value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do it with something like this:

```
    //Gets sheet data
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var data = ss.getRange("B1").getValues();
    const calculated = ss.getRange("C1");
    const value = ss.getRange("A1");
    var valueToChange = value.getValues();


    function myFunction() {
      valueToChange = +valueToChange; //change the values taken from the sheet into numbers if they are strings
      data = +data;
      valueToChange = valueToChange + data; //add them together
      value.setValue(valueToChange); //put the added number back into the sheet
    }

    //activate the above function when a specific cell is edited, in this case, B1
    function onEdit(e) {
      if (e && getFullA1Notation_(e.range) === 'Sheet1!B1') {
        myFunction();
      }
    }


    /**
    * Gets an A1 notation string like Sheet1!A2:D4.
    *
    * @param {Range} range A spreadsheet range.
    */
    function getFullA1Notation_(range) {
      return range.getSheet().getSheetName() + '!' + range.getA1Notation();
    }
```

This script takes in the data in cell A1 of the sheet (the cell you want to enter data into) and has a dropdown in cell B1 with multiple options, such as "5,10,15" (the same example as used in your question). It then takes the string from the dropdown and the string/number from the entered data, adds them together, and puts it back into cell A1 (replacing the data that was previously entered).

The script only activates once the dropdown has been edited (hence the onEdit function specifying cell B1).